# Pointer from base template class not seen in derived template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have template class List:

```
template<class T>
class List{
    protected:
    element<T>* head;
//...
};
```

And i have template class Set which inherits from List:

```
template<class T>
class Set: public List<T>{
    public:
    void insert(const T& t){
        if(!has(t))
            pushFront(t);
    }
    bool has(const T& t){
        bool is=false;
        element<T>* tmp=head;
        while(tmp && !is){
            if(Comparator::compare(t, tmp->key))
                is=true;
            tmp=tmp->next;
        }
        return is;
    }
};
```

My problem is that when I want to use head in line `element<T>* tmp=head;` without anything else, I get error `'head' was not declared in this scope` but when I add `List<T>::` before head in this line(`element<T>* tmp=List<T>::head;`) everything works fine. Why I get this error, when head is in protected and I use public inheritance?

Comment: `List<T>` is a dependent base class, use `this->head` instead

Answer (score 0):

This happen because the assignment of "`element<T>* tmp`" do not deppend of T parameter,
so, tmp is known as a nondependent name. On the other hand, List is dependent on
template parameter T so List is called a dependent name.

The problem: The compiler does not look in dependent base classes (like List) when looking
up nondependent names (like head).

Solutions:

1. Change the call from head to this->head. Since this is always implicitly dependent in a template,
   this->head is dependent and the lookup is therefore deferred until the template is actually instantiated,
   at which point all base classes are considered.
2. Change the call from tmp=head to `element<T>::head`. This is your current solution, but, take in care...
   If head being a virtual function this might not give you what you want, since it inhibits the virtual
   dispatch mechanism.